# WooCommerce - Exclude category from snippet

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use the following snippet to display extra text after the price in WooCommerce:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
function custom_price_message( $price ) {
  $new_price = $price . ' <span class="price-text">' . __('with shipping').'</span>';
  return $new_price;
}
```

But now it shows on every product page. Is it possible to exclude a certain product category from this? Not all products include shipping. So I thought I'd make a new category named "Pick up only", place all the products that don't have shipping in there and exclude that category from the above snippet. However, I don't know how to do this... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated!

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Since product category is a taxonomy, you could try the [`is_tax()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) function. Check for the current category and then manipulate the data:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
function custom_price_message( $price ) {
  // Check the current category
  if ( ! is_tax ( 'product_cat', 'category name or id here' ) {
      $price .= ' <span class="price-text">' . __('with shipping').'</span>';
  }
  return $price;
}
```